# How to paste vector elements into a string accordingly?

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, vector, paste

I'm using C++98, I have a `vector` with the elements `13` `m` `1.5` `0.6` and I would like to paste them into this string accordingly.

`The length of Object 1 is %d%s, weight is %dkg, friction coefficient = %f.`

The output will be

`The length of Object 1 is 13m, weight is 1.5kg, friction coefficient = 0.6.`

I tried it in a for loop but I'm not sure how to update the string after paste the 1st element. Any idea on this?

Thanks for help.

Edited:

The `vector` and `str` are just example. While, the number of element in `vector` will always be the same as the number of delimiter (%d, %s, %f) in the `str`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> values;
    values.push_back("13");
    values.push_back("m");
    values.push_back("1.5");
    values.push_back("0.6");

    string str = "The length of Object 1 is %d%s, weight is %dkg, friction coefficient = %f.";
    string str2 = "%d";
    string str_crop;
    string unk;
    string final;

    size_t found = str.find(str2);
    if (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        str_crop = str.substr(0, found);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        unk = values[i];
        str_crop += unk;
    }
    final = str_crop;
    cout << final << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please show your code, [mcve]

Comment: In C++ you could use the boost [format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) library. In C you might use [sprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: Assuming you have to use the C format specifiers in your code for some reason, look up `std::sprintf()`  (but remember to check required buffer lengths as `sprintf()` ASSUMES it is writing to a long-enough buffer, and has undefined behaviour if that assumption is untrue).   In C++ (as distinct from using C techniques in C++) use a `std::ostrstream`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 hi, the code was added.

Comment: Does formatting option has sense, as your input are `std::string`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Is there any example to apply formatting option? I can't use the boost format library .

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what you meant to do, I'd say you could use printf but since you want to use  `cout` I suggest using a logic somewhat like this:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string> //included string for find, length and replace
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> values;
    values.push_back("13");
    values.push_back("m");
    values.push_back("1.5");
    values.push_back("0.6");

    string str = "The length of Object 1 is %v%v, weight is %vkg, friction coefficient = %v.";
    string str2 = "%v"; //i have swapped the "%d" to make it a "%v", representating value, to make it not too similar to C
    string final;
    int valloc = 1; //if you ever decide to add more values to that vector
    
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        int oc = str.find(str2);
        if (oc < str.length()+1 && oc > -1) {
            final=str.replace(oc,2,values[i+(valloc-1)]);
        }
    }
    std::cout << final;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Explaining what it does is:

1- takes a string

2- finds every occurance of the string's `%v` to replace

3- replaces it with the proper value from the vector

Comment: Was it helpfull?